# Getting user_defined_filter correct in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to get a simple Airflow (v1.9.0) `user_defined_filters` working based on the [Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja). Here is a minimal example I am trying to get running

```
def userfilter(id):
    return 'Hello' + id

default_args = {
        'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 19),
        'user_defined_filters': dict(hello=lambda name: 'Hello%s' % name, filter2=userfilter),
        }

dag = DAG('mwe', default_args=default_args)
jinja_env = dag.get_template_env()
print(jinja_env.filters)

t1 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='helloworld',
#    endpoint="/api/{{ 'world' | filter2 }}",
    endpoint="/api/{{ 'world' | hello }}",
    method='GET',
    headers=None,
    response_check=None, 
    extra_options=None, 
    xcom_push=True, 
    http_conn_id='myconn',
    dag=dag)
```

Ultimately I want `userfilter` called with values I pull from `xcom`. But, even in this simple example, I am getting an exception:

```
{base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
{base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'hello'`
```

`print(jinja_env.filters)` is also not showing the custom filters that are defined. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter you are trying to use is not a part of `default_args` but a parameter of the class `DAG`:

```
dag = DAG('mwe', 
          default_args=default_args),
          user_defined_filters=dict(hello=lambda name: 'Hello%s' % name, filter2=userfilter)
          )
```

See https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/models.html

Comment: Wonderful. That was the mistake; working now. I was a little surprised by the lack of examples for this even with a lot of googling.